# how to design lua program corrected?

Tags: c, lua

I'm a lua newbie, I have a question that nagged me several days.

For example, in c language, I have a struct as below:

```
struct userinfo{
    int id,
    char *name,
    int age
}
```

If I want to define different user's info, I can do like this:

```
struct userinfo user1;
struct userinfo user2;
```

but in lua, I don't know how to implement this function correctly. I think I can do it as below:

```
local userinfo = {}

function userinfo.new(param)
    local self = {id = param.id, name = param.name, age = param.age}
    return self
end

return userinfo

local info = require "userinfo"
local user1 = info.new({id = 1, name = "xxx", age = 20})
local user2 = info.new({id = 2, name = "yyy", age = 20})
```

this looks like satisfy my demand,but feel weird.

I want to know how to design program using lua's own way,instead of c's.

please show me the code, or provide some documents. thanks very much!

Comment: This feels like perfectly idiomatic Lua code. Good job! Why do you think it's weird?

Comment: For pure data fields (i.e., no functions in the table), there is no need to use a "new" function like in your example. Just declare the table normally. Also, you're allocating temporary tables and copying them for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid creating the temporary tables to pass parameters. That would use less memory and be a little faster.

```
local userinfo = {}

function userinfo.new(id, name, age)
  return {id = id, name = name, age = age}
end

return userinfo

---

local info = require "userinfo"
local user1 = info.new(1, "xxx", 20)
local user2 = info.new(2, "yyy", 20)
```

Note however that in Lua it's totally ok to just use raw tables. The following is perfectly acceptable (and the fastest solution):

```
local user1 = {id = 1, name = "xxx", age = 20}
local user2 = {id = 2, name = "yyy", age = 20}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but I also have a question. if in a large project, many difference modules will use the userinfo. how different people can know what fields the userinfo contains? in c language,they can read the struct userinfo, but in lua, what can I do? Maybe we can view the documents or comments.

Comment: You can either use comments our source code. For example, I sometimes add checks to the begining of my user-facing functions which do things like `checkInteger(id); checkString(name); checkNumber(age)` etc. That way people can read "ok, id needs to be an integer". I only do this on the "outward-facing" entry points of my library, not in all functions.